# What are the set theoretic properties of vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, definition, physics

I am reading introductory Quantum Mechanics, where it says-

> For a classical system, the space of states is a set (the set of
> possible states), and the logic of classical physics is Boolean. The space of states of a quantum system is not a mathematical set; it is a vector space.

Further, in the footnote, it says-

> To be a little more precise, we will not focus on the set-theoretic
> properties of state spaces, even though they may, of course, be regarded as sets.

What does "set-theoretic
properties of state spaces" mean?

Comment: This is an unusual excerpt. Where does it come from?  I suspect you should just ignore the footnote, and ignore when it says "is not a mathematical set."

Comment: @Michael This comes from Leonard Susskind's Lectures

Comment: I think it is just an awkward way of saying he will focus on linear algebra rather than topology.  The only precise mathematical meaning I can think of for "is not a mathematical set" would be when something is "too large to be a set" but that is likely a completely different concept than what is being used here.  The footnote itself contradicts the phrase "is not a mathematical set" when it says it may **of course** be regarded as a set.

Comment: I think that by "not a mathematical set" he just means that it's a tuple $(V,\mathbb{F},+,\cdot)$ and not just $V$. At least, when he writes about "mathematical sets" in "The Theoretical Minimum" he gives examples of finite sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think @Michael's comments may be onto something, I have my own guess as to what Susskind means. A vector space is an ordered $4$-tuple $\mathcal{V}:=(V,\,\Bbb K,\,+,\,\cdot)$, with $+$ telling us how to add elements of $V$, and $\cdot$ telling us how to multiply them by elements of the field $\Bbb K$. I won't repeat all the vector space axioms you probably already know. The important point is that the vector space is not just $V$ itself. But we cheat the set theory a little:

- elements of $V$ will often, in an [abuse of notation/terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation), be called elements of $\mathcal{V}$, which in turn may just be called $V$;
- we don't care about the details of how your favourite set theory [defines an ordered $n$-tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Definitions).